# I want to divide User db into multiple array and get the array that the current_user is in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making the service that offer 2 randam users in a day.
And I am creating the logic like this.

1.Push the users db into array

2.Devide that array with 3 users

3.Get the array that the current_user(using device gem) is in and offer the users within this array

But I am stuck with the third part... - Get the array that the current_user(using device gem) is in

Any idea to create this logic?

```
arr = User.all.shuffle
arr_list = arr.each_slice(3).to_a 

[[#<User id: 3, email: “3@sample.com", created_at: "2017-07-11 10:57:14", updated_at: "2017-07-11 10:57:54">,
  #<User id: 2, email: “2@sample.com", created_at: "2017-07-11 10:14:08", updated_at: "2017-07-11 11:00:24">,
  #<User id: 6, email: “6@sample.com", created_at: "2017-07-11 10:59:14", updated_at: "2017-07-11 10:59:14">],
 [#<User id: 1, email: “1@sample.com", created_at: "2017-07-11 06:52:31", updated_at: "2017-07-11 06:52:31">,
  #<User id: 7, email: “7@sample.com", created_at: "2017-07-11 10:59:34", updated_at: "2017-07-11 10:59:44">,
  #<User id: 4, email: “4@sample.com", created_at: "2017-07-11 10:58:14", updated_at: "2017-07-11 10:58:26">],
 [#<User id: 8, email: “8@sample.com", created_at: "2017-07-11 10:59:59", updated_at: "2017-07-11 11:00:10">,
  #<User id: 5, email: “5@sample.com", created_at: "2017-07-11 10:58:44", updated_at: "2017-07-11 10:58:55">]]
```

If the current_user is 1, I want to offer user_id 7 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
other_users = arr_list.find { |arr| arr.include?(current_user) } - [current_user]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to ensure that the current user doesn't receive the offer? If that's the case, then why not do:

```
User.where.not(id: current_user).sample(2)
```